# How can I say it? "the questions whose answers I don't know" or "the questions that I don't know their answers"?

Tags: word-order, relative-pronouns

This may be silly question, looks like the first option is obvious but when I was writing some time ago I couldn't figure out until I wrote it here.  Still, I wanted to ask you to learn shortest and best way of articulation.

> the questions whose answers I don't know
>
> the questions that I don't know their answers

Comment: "There are still some unanswered questions..." is how I would say this in a formal message.  Informally you could say "What I want to know is, (question)?"

Comment: **_The questions I don't know the answers to_** is clear, concise, and perfectly acceptable.

Comment: [Here's an ELU discussion on whether you can use *whose* for inanimate objects.](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23541/can-whose-refer-to-an-inanimate-object)  Short version: there's a long history of using *whose* for inanimate objects, but it still sounds wrong to a lot of native speakers.

Comment: @P.E.Dant your answer seems the correct one sir. the answer below is missing the "to" right? could you please add your comment as "answer" so that I can mark it as "the correct answer" ?

Comment: @CeyhunÖzsoylu The first answer does include the preposition _to,_ but in a different position in the sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question posits only two possible formations of this phrase:

> - *The questions whose answers I don't know*
> - *The questions that I don't know their answers*

Of these, the second is ungrammatical. The first is acceptable, although many English speakers intuitively feel that "something is wrong" about using *whose* to refer to things instead of beings (in spite of the fact that [Shakespeare](http://www.monologuearchive.com/s/shakespeare_004.html) himself did so in ~1600CE!)

This usage can be avoided by (as noted in another answer) using the pronoun *which* instead...

> - *The questions **to which** I do not know the answers*

This may be preferable in formal writing. However, in idiomatic English, the most common form is...

> - *The questions [that] I don't know the answers **to***

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest:

- "questions to which I do not know the answer"

I'm open to comments on plurality of the word answer, I don't think it's incorrect however it suggests you're referring to some specific set of answers.